# playframework wildcard matching

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, url-routing

Say I have the following url:

```
/baseurl
```

I'd like play to match and route on this url.  I'd like to satisfy all these patterns:

```
/baseurl
/baseurl/
/baseurl/*
/baseurl/*/*
```

So basically I don't care what comes after '/baseurl'. I don't want to explicitly have to pass a variable to my action for the part coming in after '/baseurl' because I don't care about it: I just want it all routed to the same controller (for a single page app).  I also am ok if I have to do this with multiple route lines.

Comment: You can use `*paramaterName` e.g. `/baseurl/*paramaterName` for parameter matching that spans `/`.

Comment: Yes, but that still forces me to define a parameter 'parameterName' for my action method.  I don't care what is in the url so it would be nice to just match everything and forward to a parameterless action method, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put something like this pretty high in the routes file:

```
GET           /baseurl/*path/        controllers.Application.untrail(path: String)
```

(and the variations thereof)

And then in `controllers.Application`:

```
def untrail(path: String) = Action {
  MovedPermanently("/baseurl")
}
```